# Visualization:-x-labels and title for the graph created through matplotlib and seaborn are not displaying properly

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science

Please find the below image. x-label and title of graph are half displayed..Do appreciate any kind of help.ty.[image]

After applying plt.tight_layout():-[image]

But here i got the legend details(status) overlapped with the data..is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You didn't show the code, but probably adding `plt.tight_layout()` just before calling `plt.show` might help quite a bit.

Comment: It indeed helped the cause but teh legend is being overlapped with the data..any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Without showing the code that generates the plots, it is very hard to get help. See [this guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#legend-location) about how to set the location of the legend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the display size.

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))